# Adding checked variable from database with fields from database as well

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form which has a list of checkboxes to be filled in on insert to database as well as when editing. When editing I am trying to populate the fields with a list of fields from the database which is in the `$groups` variable and the checked value being checked against the `group_id` from groups with the `group_id` from the `$user`. It is working except it only fills out one checkbox and some users belong to multiple groups. Any ideas, or more efficient ways to do this.

Heres my code so far

```
<?php foreach($groups as $group) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($user['groups'] as $uG) {
        if ($uG['group_id'] == $group['id']) {
            $checked = "checked";
        } else {
            $checked = '';
        }               
    }?>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="group_id-<?php echo $group['id']; ?>">
            <input <?php echo $checked; ?> type="checkbox" name="group_id[]" id="group_id-<?php echo $group['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $group['id']; ?>">
            <?php echo $group['name']; ?>
        </label>
    </div>           
 <? endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is that you are searching all the `$users['group']` array and not stopping when you find a match, so unless last `$uG['group_id']` matches `$group['id']` you continue and therefore clear `$checked` after potentially setting it.

So just add a `break` when you find a match.

Also, officially the correct way of setting the checked status is `checked="checked"` although most modern browsers are not that pedantic, its possibly better to stick to the HTML spec

```
<?php foreach($groups as $group) : ?>
    <?php 
     $checked = '';
     foreach ($user['groups'] as $uG) {
        if ($uG['group_id'] == $group['id']) {
            $checked = 'checked="checked"';
            break;
        }               
    }?>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="group_id-<?php echo $group['id']; ?>">
            <input <?php echo $checked; ?> type="checkbox" name="group_id[]" id="group_id-<?php echo $group['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $group['id']; ?>">
            <?php echo $group['name']; ?>
        </label>
    </div>           
 <? endforeach; ?>
```

you could also use a ternary operator and `in_array()` to do this all in one simple statement

```
<?php 
    foreach($groups as $group) : 
        $checked = in_array( $group['id'], $user['groups'] ) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
?>    
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="group_id-<?php echo $group['id']; ?>">
            <input <?php echo $checked; ?> type="checkbox" name="group_id[]" id="group_id-<?php echo $group['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $group['id']; ?>">
            <?php echo $group['name']; ?>
        </label>
    </div>           
 <? endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define `$checked = '';` first then loop and change the value if match found

```
<?php foreach($groups as $group) : ?>
    <?php 
    $checked = '';
    foreach ($user['groups'] as $uG) {
        if ($uG['group_id'] == $group['id']) {
            $checked = "checked";
        }               
    }?>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="group_id-<?php echo $group['id']; ?>">
            <input <?php echo $checked; ?> type="checkbox" name="group_id[]" id="group_id-<?php echo $group['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $group['id']; ?>">
            <?php echo $group['name']; ?>
        </label>
    </div>           
 <? endforeach; ?>
```